# add repository response model includes?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, include, repository, addition

I have a working add repository. I want to write a separate add repository without touching it, but after adding it in this repository, I want it to return a value that is included in the response model. How can I do it ?

MyRepository

```
     public class Repository<T> : IRepository<T> where T : EntityBase
       {
          private readonly ApplicationContext Context;

     public Repository(ApplicationContext context)
       {
          Context = context;
       }

    public async Task<T> AddAsync(T entity)
    {
        Context.Set<T>().Add(entity);
        await Context.SaveChangesAsync();
        return entity;
    }

    public async Task<IEnumerable<T>> GetAllAsync(Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate = null, 
    IList<string> includes = null, bool disableTracking = true)
    {
        IQueryable<T> query = Context.Set<T>().Where(x => !x.IsDelete);

        if (predicate != null) query = query.Where(predicate);

        if (includes != null)
            query = includes.Aggregate(query, (current, include) => current.Include(include));

        if (disableTracking) query = query.AsNoTracking();

        return await query.ToListAsync();
    }
```

Comment: Can you describe more in detail what you're trying to archive? Do you want to create a new class that inherits from `Repository`?

Comment: I want my TreatmentTitle, ProductName, BrandName fields to come as include, not null and I want to create a new generic repository method                                            {
  "Data": {
    "ProductId": 2,
    "TreatmentId": 4,
    "TreatmentTitle": null,
    "ProductName": null,
    "BrandId": 4,
    "BrandName": null,
 
  },
  "Success": true,
  "Message": null
}

Comment: Still not 100% sure, but I have an idea :) 
So the properties are comming from relations? You would have to load the required relations explicit:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data/explicit

You could create an overload of the AddAsync method, that accepts relations

Comment: Yes, the ProductPrice table is associated with the Brand table. When I want to record a data, I want to get BrandName next to the brandId in the response that is returned to me after recording. I want to write a new repo for it

Comment: You could make the AddAsync method virtual, create a new repo that inherits from your current repo class, overwrites the AddAsync method and loads the required relations after adding it to the db

Comment: I'm asking this too. I do not know how to do it